# how to configure proxy or web server to keep URL in browser unchanged

Tags: apache, networking, nginx, proxy, dns

This question comes to me today.
my github page is at [io](http://rugal.github.io).
I have applied two free domain name. first one is  [ml](http://rugal.ml)  the other one is [ga](http://rugal.ga)

Because of the low connection speed, I am using DNSpod(a DNS resolve server) to accelerate the `ml`, which is a request redirection service, hence when I visiting `ml`, it will jump back to `io`, also while I clicking a link on it, the `URL` in my browser will surely change.

For instance:
`http://rugal.github.io/pages/archive.html`  and
`http://rugal.github.io/pages/projects.html`

But here is a very big miracle, another domain name `ga`, which I did not have any enhancement to it but only configured it to URL forward to `io`, turn out to have a very magical phenomena. I found the `URL` in browser would not change even if I click any hyper-link in it.

I am a Java programmer myself for about three years, I know some basic conceptions about network proxy and DNS resolution. and I think this magic may be configured in `apache url rewrite` or some sort of behavior of `web server`

Here I am asking how to achieve the function that I have mentioned in my question.
As this is the first question I asked, I am trying to make it clarified, and please do not regard this question as an `AD` or some sort.
I got puzzle for a whole night!

### UPDATE

I dont think this is caused by `<frameset>` tag in html, because my github page is generated by `jekyll` which seems have no `<frameset>` tag in it.
Also, even if there has `<frameset>` in it, why the `ml` URL changing all the time, but `ga` never change? they pointing to totally the same website `rugal.github.io`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a frameset:

```
 <frameset rows="*">
    <frame frameborder=0 src="http://rugal.ml" name="dot_tk_frame_content" scrolling="auto" noresize>
  </frameset>
</html>
```

The original document at `rugal.ga` contains a frame in which the other pages are embedded. It's like a browser inside a browser. Only the main document's URL is displayed in the address bar, so that never changes.

It's not a great practice for many reasons, one of them is that your visitors don't see the address of the current document.

Comment: as mentioned above, my github page is made from jekyll, and I do not think it contained the `frameset` you have mentioned. in addition, while visiting `ml`, the URL will change, how you could explain this?  As two domain name actually pointing to the same `rugal.github.io`. hence I think it is the function of proxy server that matter, not `html` code in it!

Comment: It's the rugal.ga that is injecting the frame code. It's a popular way among web hosts to forward to a different domain. The .ml URLs will change because they don't have the frame injected. It's not a proxy issue.

Comment: really？ that is a good notion! you mean the DNS server injected the response with `<frameset>` ? Could you please tell how it inject? many thanks!

Comment: I agree that this is not a good practice! thank you, I will check the injected code tonight

Comment: I found it in my page from `rugal.ga`, seems DNS server injected it, or some other network facilities, while `rugal.ml` did not! thanks you !!!